# How to parse json with key and value?

Tags: android, json, parsing

I have to get bitcoin money for every week. And if I use JsonObject, then I get the json, BUT I CAN NOT USE THE CYCLE to take all the data. And if I use JSONObject, then retured null. Please,Help me!

This is my api:

https://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/historical/close.json?start=2018-08-01&end=2018-08-19

```
{"bpi":{"2018-08-01":7603.7488,"2018-08-02":7535.02,"2018-08-03":7415.5613,"2018-08-04":7009.0888,"2018-08-05":7026.9913,"2018-08-06":6937.0738,"2018-08-07":6717.2088,"2018-08-08":6280.58,"2018-08-09":6537.9025,"2018-08-10":6143.305,"2018-08-11":6233.3813,"2018-08-12":6312.8338,"2018-08-13":6252.37,"2018-08-14":6192.3063,"2018-08-15":6270.0425,"2018-08-16":6314.2413,"2018-08-17":6583.2388,"2018-08-18":6395.3525},"disclaimer":"This data was produced from the CoinDesk Bitcoin Price Index. BPI value data returned as USD.","time":{"updated":"Aug 19, 2018 13:06:45 UTC","updatedISO":"2018-08-19T13:06:45+00:00"}}
```

Comment: Review the answer below, have verified my self working as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Gson`,  simply add below code in your model class.

```
@SerializedName("bpi")
JsonElement results;

public Map<String, String> getResults() {
    Type type = new TypeToken<Map<String, String>>() {}.getType();

    final Map<String, String> objects = new Gson().fromJson(results, type);
    return objects;
}
```

Here is how your model class will look like

```
public class Model {
    @SerializedName("disclaimer")
    private String disclaimer;

    @SerializedName("time")
    private Time time;

    @SerializedName("bpi")
    JsonElement results;

    public Map<String, String> getResults() {
        Type type = new TypeToken<Map<String, String>>() {}.getType();
        final Map<String, String> objects = new Gson().fromJson(results, type);
        return objects;
    }

    public String getDisclaimer() {
        return disclaimer;
    }

    public void setDisclaimer(String disclaimer) {
        this.disclaimer = disclaimer;
    }

    public Time getTime() {
        return time;
    }

    public void setTime(Time time) {
        this.time = time;
    }

    public class Time {

        @SerializedName("updated")
        private String updated;

        @SerializedName("updatedISO")
        private String updatedISO;

        public String getUpdated() {
            return updated;
        }

        public void setUpdated(String updated) {
            this.updated = updated;
        }

        public String getUpdatedISO() {
            return updatedISO;
        }

        public void setUpdatedISO(String updatedISO) {
            this.updatedISO = updatedISO;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is your API interface method

```
@GET("/v1/bpi/historical/close.json")
Call<Model> getData(@Query("start") String start,@Query("end") String end);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use like below to parse data

```
 JSONObject sys  = reader.getJSONObject("bpi");
 String country = sys.getString("2018-08-01");
```

If it is dynamic then you may use like below

```
JSONObject mainJSONObj=new JSONObject(<json_string>);
// get category JSONObject from mainJSONObj
JSONObject categoryJSONObj=mainJSONObj.getJSONObject("category");
// get all keys from categoryJSONObj
Iterator<String> iterator = categoryJSONObj.keys();
  while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    String key = iterator.next();
    Log.i("TAG","key:"+key +"--Value::"+categoryJSONObj.optString(key);
  }
```

Anyway you can try Retrofit & Gson to parse and make it model and easy parsing.

Comment: If I use JSONObject it return null data. But If I use JsonObject, its worked.

Comment: Your JsonObject is from `com.google.gson.JsonObject` and JSONObject is from `org.json.JSONObject`